# Drawer navigation screen broken, after parent state has changed

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

When I change state from custom bottom bar (Parent root's state), screen looks weird. I don't catch my mistake.

Does parent screen's state affect on the child screens width?

```
 const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = useState<any>();

  <NavigationContainer
    ref={navigationRef}>
    {loginState?.loginToken === null ? (
      <AuthStackScreens />
    ) : (
        <AppContainer />
    )}
  </NavigationContainer>
```

AppContainer's structure looks like this.

```
  - Stack.Navigator
      - Drawer.Navigator
         - Stack Navigation 1 (Tabbar: Custom bottom bar)
           - Contact
           - Others ...
         - Stack Navigation 2 
      - ...
      - ...
      - ...
```

[image]

I hope you guys suggest me solution.

Comment: Check this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#uselegacyimplementation ...This may help

Comment: @Irfanwani yes of course. I suppose someone may face to this problem, and know the solution. Thanks your comment :)

Comment: how do you present the drawer? use the state status or useRef hook?

Comment: can you share me expo link ?

Comment: Thank you guys to left a comment. I removed the transition from drawer, and now it works fine temporary. But I didn't find the reason why it happens.

Comment: @GauravRoy it's created by react cli :>>